# laravel eloquent serialize custom relation with multi tables

Tags: php, laravel

I use

```
"laravel/framework": "^8.54",
```

and in my db structure I have model which aggregate different properties by id and set discriminator column for identity with what exactly table this is realtion, like this

sql

```
create table configure_property_estates
(
    id                    bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    estates_id            bigint unsigned not null,
    configure_property_id bigint unsigned not null,
    discriminator         varchar(100)    not null,
    created_at            timestamp       null,
    updated_at            timestamp       null,
    constraint configure_property_estates_estates_id_foreign
        foreign key (estates_id) references estates (id)
            on delete cascade
);

create index configure_property_estates_configure_property_id_index
    on configure_property_estates (configure_property_id);
```

json response

```
 "configure_property_estates": [
      {
        "id": 28,
        "estates_id": 14,
        "configure_property_id": 1,
        "discriminator": "ConfigureEstatePropertyKitchen",
        "created_at": "2021-10-10T15:17:46.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-10T15:17:46.000000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 29,
        "estates_id": 14,
        "configure_property_id": 1,
        "discriminator": "ConfigureEstatePropertyRequirements",
        "created_at": "2021-10-10T15:17:47.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-10T15:17:47.000000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "estates_id": 14,
        "configure_property_id": 2,
        "discriminator": "ConfigureEstatePropertyType",
        "created_at": "2021-10-10T15:17:47.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-10T15:17:47.000000Z"
      }
    ],
```

this model, without FK only index:

```
class ConfigurePropertyEstates extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'estates_id',
        'configure_property_id',
        'discriminator'
    ];

    public function getTable()
    {
        return 'configure_property_estates';
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the estates that are assigned this conf.
     */
    public function estates()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Estates::class, 'estates_id');
    }
}
```

os, my quesiton what need to do if I want extend json interpretation for this model by configure properties model, like this

```
  {
    "id": 28,
    "estates_id": 14,
    "configure_property_id": 1,
    "configure_property": {
        "id": 1,
        "some_property_column": "test"
    }
    "discriminator": "ConfigureEstatePropertyKitchen",
    "created_at": "2021-10-10T15:17:46.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-10-10T15:17:46.000000Z"
  },
```

Do exist some way for that, some type of relation or could be some custom approach for resole this case ?

**UPDATE**

I added this code to my model `ConfigurePropertyEstates` and this is works like I expected

```
public function toArray()
{
    $toArray = parent::toArray();
    $nameSpaceDiscriminator = EstatePropertiesService::fetchNameSpaceDiscriminator($toArray['discriminator']);
    if (!class_exists($nameSpaceDiscriminator)) {
        throw new \Exception('class ' . $nameSpaceDiscriminator . ' does not exist');
    }
    $toArray['configure_property'] = $nameSpaceDiscriminator::whereId($toArray['configure_property_id'])->first();
    return $toArray;
}
```

response

```
  {
    "id": 28,
    "estates_id": 14,
    "configure_property_id": 1,
    "discriminator": "ConfigureEstatePropertyKitchen",
    "created_at": "2021-10-10T15:17:46.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-10-10T15:17:46.000000Z",
    "configure_property": {
      "id": 1,
      "property_name": "test",
      "property_value": "tets",
      "available": 1,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    }
  },
```

But look like some custom hack, any vision on this suggestion ?

Comment: do you mean [polymorphic-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I updated my question, added UPDATE section